# Can't get data from table using function belongsToMany

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to store students data in array with groups data. For example:

```
groups

id - 1
name - P1
student_id - 1

id - 2
name - P1
student_id - 2

id - 3
name - P2
student_id - 3
```

Here I want gate data like this

```
[
  {name: 'P1', students: [{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liza'}]},
  {name: 'P2', students: [{id: 3, name: 'Bob'}]},
]
```

**Tables:**

```
users

id - bigint unsigned
name - string
...other columns
```

groups

```
id - bigint unsigned
name - string
student_id
...other columns
```

**Group.php model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Groups extends Model
{
    public $table = "groups";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'groups', 'student_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function groupsAdmin(){
   return view("groups", ["groups" => Groups::with(['students'])->get()]);
}
```

With this code I'm getting empty students array.

Comment: Rework your database design, you have two groups named `P1` with different keys. And you relations are inverted. User should have a column `group_id` (if a user can have _ONE_ group only)

Comment: @kerbholz Thank you for your replay, I will change my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its, belongsToMany from users to groups so it should be like this.

you need another table(pivot table), name it group_user.

```
group_user table:-
user_id
group_id
```

and completely remove the student_id from grups table.

now go to User model and put this method:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

and go to Group Model and put this code

```
 public function users()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
 }
```

with this code above, you can access groups from user and users from a group, like so:

```
$user = User::first();
$groups = $user->groups;
```

Hope this helps, see the Doc here:
[Eloquent Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)